# How do semantic actions (using _val and _attr) influence rule definition with %= and x3::rule's force_attribute=true?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, boost-spirit-x3

Given semantic actor

```
template<typename ValueType>
class divide
{
public:
  divide(ValueType value) : divisor{value} {}

  template<typename ContextType>
  void operator()(ContextType& context) const
  {
    _val(context) /= divisor;
  }
private:
  const ValueType divisor;
};
```

it seems I'm hitting the fact that the presence of semantic actions inhibit attribute synthesis (or propagation?), i.e.

```
const auto norm = x3::rule<struct _, double>{"norm"}
                = x3::double_[normalize{100.}];
```

gives me the value 0.

So I tried forcing attribute propagation by using `%=`

```
const auto norm_rule = x3::rule<struct _, double>{"norm"}
                    %= x3::double_[normalize{100.}];
```

This gives me the expected parsed value divided by 100.

Then I discovered `x3::rule` has a third template argument, `bool force_attribute`, and noticed that

```
const auto norm_rule = x3::rule<struct _, double, true>{"norm"}
                     = x3::double_[divide{100.}];
```

Has the wanted result of the value divided by 100.

Experimenting further, I also discovered I could instead define `divide::operator()` as follows:

```
void operator()(ContextType& context)
{
  _attr(context) = _val(context) / divisor;
}
```

This last one seems to strongly couple/condemn the semantic actor to a rule's top level, as it acts on the attribute `_attr` of the first rule instead of the value `_val` of a parser to which it is attached.

Am I correct in my deduction that

1. `%=` is the same as setting the third `x3::rule` template parameter `force_attribute` to true?
2. This type of value-processing semantic actions should exclusively work on `_val` so they work on the attached parser instead of the first `rule` encountered in the hierarchy?

I understand these may seem lie unrelated questions, but they really are connected as I'm trying to process a parsed number (float) and transform it into an uint8 in several ways. To be totally complete: I have working code (numeric stuff [here](https://github.com/skui-org/skui/blob/a72f5704a08c8487f285efb9a5564b7144aa4338/css/grammar/numeric.h%2B%2B) and the actual thing I'm constructing/parsing [here](https://github.com/skui-org/skui/blob/a72f5704a08c8487f285efb9a5564b7144aa4338/css/grammar/color.h%2B%2B)), but it seems needlessly complex (due to the above it seems I need a rule per type/value transformation, which seems silly.

Comment: Hmm it seems I swapped the meaning of `_attr`  and `_val`. The former should be the attached parser's result, and the latter should be the rule's attribute. At least I can understand my own confusion. I'll leave the question as is for now, until I get grips on this I fear changing it will make it worse than it is now.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems I'm hitting the fact that the presence of semantic actions inhibit attribute synthesis (or propagation?)

It is so, the behavior was copied from Qi ([`qi::rule` docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics), [`How Do Rules Propagate Their Attributes?`](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/01/15/how-do-rules-propagate-attributes/)).

Relevant code parts: [call site](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/b4c5ef702bf6c28e964a84c9e9abe1a6549bce69/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp#L334-L340), [handling](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/b4c5ef702bf6c28e964a84c9e9abe1a6549bce69/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp#L273-L293).

> `%=` is the same as setting the third `x3::rule` template parameter `force_attribute` to true?

Yes, it is not documented, see the code [`boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/b4c5ef702bf6c28e964a84c9e9abe1a6549bce69/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L81-L106).

> Experimenting further, I also discovered I could instead define
>   `divide::operator()` as follows:
>
> ```
> void operator()(ContextType& context)
> {
>   _attr(context) = _val(context) / divisor;
> }
> ```
>
> This last one seems to strongly couple/condemn the semantic actor to a
>   rule's top level, as it acts on the attribute `_attr` of the first rule
>   instead of the value `_val` of a parser to which it is attached.

You got it almost right, but swapped them. It should be `_val(context) = _attr(context) / divisor`, details are below.

> This type of value-processing semantic actions should exclusively work on `_val` so they work on the attached parser instead of the first `rule` encountered in the hierarchy?

The [semantic actions documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) describes what `_val` and `_attr` is:

```
Function  Description                                         Example
--------  --------------------------------------------------  -----------------------
_val      A reference to the attribute of the innermost rule  _val(ctx) = "Gotya!"
          that directly or indirectly invokes the parser p    
_attr     A reference to the attribute of the parser p        _val(ctx) += _attr(ctx)
```

What they will be in a particular situation depends on `make_attribute`/`transform_attribute` traits. By default they will reference to the same value until you have nested rules with different attribute types ([relevant code](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/ea9c54ab0e21fdce94fbcee8af14c590188b79b4/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp#L18-L42)).

P.S. I cannot say anything about the reason why it is so. I see that many Spirit users just use `%=` all over the place because intuitively it should be a default, and you can manually disable propagation with `omit` directive. Moreover, Qi has some bugs because of this mechanism when you use lazy values on something like `repeat` directive ([ticket 13313](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13313)).