# Boost Spirit X3: What is the difference between `_val` and `_attr`?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

I am looking into Boost Spirit X3, but am struggling to fully grasp the difference between `x3::_val` and `x3::_attr` as used in semantic actions to extract attributes from the passed context. The [official docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) state

> _val: A reference to the attribute of the innermost rule that directly or indirectly invokes the parser p
> _attr: A reference to the attribute of the parser p

which doesn't really help me. I researched some and stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703199/3907364, which states

> x3::_val(ctx) is like qi::_val
> x3::_attr(ctx) is like qi::_0 (or qi::_1 for simple parsers)

but unfortunately, I was unsuccessful at figuring out what `qi::_val` and `qi::_0`/`qi::_1` are - or more precisely what their difference is.

Finally, I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/53971888/3907364, where it is stated that

> What they [`x3::_val` and `x3::_attr`] will be in a particular situation depends on make_attribute/transform_attribute traits. By default they will reference to the same value until you have nested rules with different attribute types

which seems to conform with experiments that I have conducted thus far - except I have not yet managed for `_attr` and `_val` to yield different values.

Even though I was unable to understand their difference yet, it seems rather relevant as all examples that I have seen, that use semantic actions to e.g. compute the result of a given calculation (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67256314/3907364)) always seem to use `_attr` as a more global state, whereas `_val` seems to be the immediate state of the thing that has just been parsed. E.g.

```
[](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _val(ctx) * _attr(ctx); }
```

Yet with all of this, I am still not quite able to point my finger to the *exact* difference in semantics between the two properties. Could someone perhaps try to rephrase Boost's docs and give an example of where the difference is actually important/visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> _val: A reference to the attribute of the innermost rule that directly or indirectly invokes the parser p
> _attr: A reference to the attribute of the parser p

Since this didn't help you, let's illustrate.

I like to call `_attr` the (accessor for) the [synthesized attribute](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/primitive_attributes.html):

> Parsers and generators in Spirit are fully attributed. Spirit.Qi parsers always expose an attribute specific to their type. ***This is called synthesized attribute*** as it is returned from a successful match representing the matched input sequence.
>
> For instance, numeric parsers, such as `int_` or `double_`, return the `int`
> or `double` value converted from the matched input sequence. Other
> primitive parser components have other intuitive attribute types, such
> as for instance `int_` which has `int`, or `ascii::char_` which has `char`

On the other hand, there is the attribute *bound* to the rule when invoking a parser, the `_val(ctx)`. This depends on what context you use it in.

Here's a demonstration program illustrating the differences:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dab61f78e04694e)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::core::demangle;
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {
    using boost::fusion::at_c;

    auto action = [](auto& ctx) {
        using Synthesized = decltype(_attr(ctx));
        using Bound       = decltype(_val(ctx));

        std::cout << "synthesized: " << demangle(typeid(Synthesized).name()) << "\n";
        std::cout << "bound:       " << demangle(typeid(Bound).name()) << "\n";

        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<x3::unused_type, std::decay_t<Bound>>) {
            at_c<0>(_val(ctx)) = at_c<0>(_attr(ctx));
            at_c<1>(_val(ctx)) = at_c<1>(_attr(ctx));
        }
    };

    auto expr = (x3::int_ >> x3::int_)[action];
    template <typename T> auto rule = x3::rule<struct Tag, T>{"rule"} = expr;
} // namespace Parser

template <typename T = x3::unused_type> void test() {
    static constexpr std::string_view input = "123 234";

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<x3::unused_type, T>) {
        phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::rule<T>, x3::space);
        std::cout << " -> (no attribute)\n\n";
    } else {
        T attr;
        phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::rule<T>, x3::space, attr);

        std::cout << " -> " << boost::fusion::as_vector(attr) << "\n\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    test();
    test<boost::fusion::deque<int, int>>();
    test<std::pair<int, int>>();
    test<std::tuple<int, int>>();
}
```

Printing:

```
synthesized: boost::fusion::deque<int, int>
bound:       boost::spirit::x3::unused_type
 -> (no attribute)

synthesized: boost::fusion::deque<int, int>
bound:       boost::fusion::deque<int, int>
 -> (123 234)

synthesized: boost::fusion::deque<int, int>
bound:       std::pair<int, int>
 -> (123 234)

synthesized: boost::fusion::deque<int, int>
bound:       std::tuple<int, int>
 -> (123 234)
```

Note that the action is completely redundant here, just used to add output:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a19da1837d025c5f)**

```
template <typename T = x3::unused_type> void test() {
    static constexpr std::string_view input = "123 234";

    T attr;
    phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), x3::int_ >> x3::int_, x3::space, attr);

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<x3::unused_type, T>)
        std::cout << " -> (no attribute)\n";
    else
        std::cout << " -> " << boost::fusion::as_vector(attr) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    test();
    test<boost::fusion::deque<int, int>>();
    test<std::pair<int, int>>();
    test<std::tuple<int, int>>();
}
```

Still printing

```
 -> (no attribute)
 -> (123 234)
 -> (123 234)
 -> (123 234)
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `_val(ctx)` yields the attribute of the *rule* the parser is contained in (if any), whereas `_attr(ctx)` yields the attribute of the *parser itself*. The job of a semantic action (usually) is to propagate

```
_val(ctx) <- _attr(ctx)
```

Note: `_attr(ctx)` will already have been set by the parser itself while/after having parsed the corresponding part in the input.

---

After some more trials and research, I think I have found the answer. It turns out that the official docs are (of course) correct, albeit they have phrased it somewhat more complicated than (I think) it needs to be.

First of all: An example, where the difference between `_val` and `_attr` becomes apparent ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1Mj4rYY8T)):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {

auto transform = [](auto &ctx) {
  std::cout << "Type of _val: " << typeid(x3::_val(ctx)).name()
            << "\nType of _attr: " << typeid(x3::_attr(ctx)).name() << "\n";
  x3::_val(ctx) = std::to_string(x3::_attr(ctx));
};

x3::rule<struct literal, std::string> literal{"literal"};

auto literal_def = x3::int_[transform];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(literal);

} // namespace Parser

int main() {
  std::string output;
  std::string input = "25";
  x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), Parser::literal, x3::space, output);
  std::cout << "Output: " << output << "\n";
}
```

Here, we define a rule `literal` that has a `std::string` attribute. The rule consists of only a single parser: an `x3::int_` parser, whose attribute is of type `int`.

If we omit the `transform` semantic action, this snippet will fail to compile since automatic attribute propagation will try to convert the attribute of a rule's parser(s) to the rule's attribute(s) (and `int` can't implicitly be converted to `std::string`).

Inside the `transform` action, we explicitly print the type of `_val` and `_attr`, which yields `std::string` and `int` respectively.
Therefore, we can conclude that `_attr(ctx)` yields a reference to the attribute of the parser that has parsed the given portion of the input (aka: the parser we added the action to), whereas `_val(ctx)` yields a reference to the attribute *of the rule* this parser belongs to (if the corresponding rule doesn't have an attribute or there is no such rule to begin with, this will yield `x3::unused_parameter`).

Overall, our `transform` action simply converts the parser's attribute to the rule's one, making everything work.

Without explicitly specifying a semantic action, this conversion is done automatically, as can be seen in this example ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6d1ocafEe):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {

auto dummy = [](auto &ctx) {
};

x3::rule<struct literal, int> literal{"literal"};

auto literal_def = x3::int_;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(literal);

} // namespace Parser

int main() {
  int output;
  std::string input = "25";
  x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), Parser::literal, x3::space, output);
  std::cout << "Output: " << output << "\n";
}
```

However, as soon as we insert a semantic action, this has to be done explicitly, which can be observed by adding the dummy action to the `int_` parser like so:

```
x3::int_[dummy]
```

While the `output` variable was set to `25` (as expected) before, it now remains at its default-initialized value of `0`, because the parser's attribute has never been propagated to the rule's attribute.

Comment: I see you've expended a similar amount of energy :) Re: _"After some more trials and research, I think I have found the answer"_ - what question did that answer, I didn't detect that problem from your question above? If so, that's a frequently asked question, sadly: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+semantic+propagation+automatic; slightly less so since X3: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20semantic%20propagation%20automatic%20x3&searchOn=3

Comment: @sehe I was referring to having found the answer to the "what's the difference between _val and _attr" question. I just figured that I'd also put everything else that I discovered during the process (which has to do with with automatic propagation) in my answer as well as it helped me make the `_val` vs `_attr` thing more clear ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Note however, that the automatic propagation was indeed nothing that I had any issues with - it only serves as illustration as to what is going on :)

Comment: Good! Glad you got it sorted. And kudos for doing the delving on your own. It does usually work best long-term. Small caveat: X3 does occasionally change things surrounding attribute propagation and compatibility (e.g. this recently happened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673378/boost-spirit-x3-parse-into-structs/45683933#comment135826578_45683933)

Comment: @sehe ah so X3 is _still_ experimental? That's somewhat sad... Though I guess I'll simply use it anyway and hope that we won't get that many breaking changes after 8 years of it being released ^^ Thanks for the heads-up though!

Answer (score 0):

@Raven,

Examining the actual code shows _val and _attr are actually created in 3 lines starting in call.hpp [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/call.hpp#L69). That's called from action.hpp [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/action.hpp#L44), where it can be seen that `attr` comes from being synthesized by `this->subject` [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/action.hpp#L54).

But, you might ask, where does `rcontext`, the value used to make `_val` come from? Well, you have to look further up the call chain to `detail/rule.hpp` [in `call_rule_definition`](https://htmltomd.com/(https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp#L328)) where the `rcontext`("rule context") is assigned the same value as the "transformed" attribute, `attr_`. Now, `attr_` **USUALLY** will be the same as the actual rule attribute, `attr` depending on what the "customization point", [transform::pre](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp#L311) does. The default `transform::pre` does make `attr_` the same as `attr`. But is `attr` actually the rule's attribute? That, again, frustratingly, depends on from where `call_rule_definition` is called.

There are 2 places where `call_rule_definition` is called from:

1. directly from [rule_definition::parse](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L62).
2. indirectly, from [rule::parse](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L155) via the [`generated parse_rule`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L213) which [directly calls `call_rule_definition`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L221).

   Now, what may puzzle you, after careful code study, is why `transform_attribute` `pre` and `post` are called twice in this case:

   1. [in `rule::parse directly`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L153)
   2. [indirectly in `call_rule_defintion`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp#L311)

      That call is made indirectly, as previously mentioned, through [the generated `parse_rule`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L219).

   Now, @Raven, you might ask yourself, "why not just move the `transform_attribute` code from `call_rule_definition` to `rule_definition::parse` and thereby eliminate the duplicate `transform_attribute`?" I've repeatedly asked myself that question and can think of no downside. @sehe, can you think of some reason why this change would not be good?

Comment: ah that indeed looks rather convoluted. As someone not involved with any X3 coding, refactoring this to make behavior more streamlined sounds like a good idea. Thanks for sharing your findings!